# Does Kafka's message include timestamp by default?

Tags: apache-kafka

Does Kafka's message include timestamp by default? Or it required to put timestamp in body message manually if needed?

Comment: Not yet, but you can add it into the header.

Comment: In messages header? Could you show how to add and get? Is it bettter than add to message body?

Comment: it depends on the meaning of timestamp, in my opinion, if timestamp is business data, then the message should contains it, if it is just the timestamp of the message, then its place is in the header. What language do you use to produce message? 
Anyway if you need the timestamp of the message send event, then the broker set it to the message when ack the message.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, all Kafka messages (since 0.11) include a timestamp. This can be set [explicitly by the producer](http://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#send-org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord-org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Callback-), or [configured](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#log.message.timestamp.type) at a broker or topic level to be the timestamp at which the message was written to the topic.