# Clickhouse Kafka engine virtual column _timestamp meaning

Tags: clickhouse

In the Clickhouse Kafka engine, there are some [virtual columns](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/integrations/kafka/#virtual-columns) containing the `_timestamp` or `_timestamp_ms` fields.

Any idea what do these fields exactly mean? When the message

- was sent to Kafka
- was consumed by Clickhouse
- was stored to Clickhouse

Or something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is the timestamp from the kafka message. https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.html

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61857937/11644308

It is set by your producer or your broker